# Twitch stream with FFMpeg, multiple audio inputs

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, streaming, webcam

I'm using the following script to try and stream my linux desktop to Twitch.tv, I have the stream working, but I want to throw in 2 audio inputs into the stream (one for the game, and one for my mic)

Here's the script

```
#! /bin/bash
INRES="1900x600"
OUTRES="800x600"
INAUD="pulse"
FPS="25
STREAM_KEY=$(cat ~/.twitch_key)
STREAM_URL="rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"

ffmpeg \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i "$INAUD" \
-f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i :0.0+1280,0 \
-vcodec libx264 -s "$OUTRES" -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-acodec libmp3lame -threads 6 -qscale 5 -b 64KB \
-f flv -ar 44100 "$STREAM_URL"
```

I use Pulseaudio and have pavucontrol, if that matters. The game would be on "Build-in Audio Analog Stereo" and the mic is from the recording device "Webcam C110 Analog Mono"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That bad script again... I don't use PulseAudio, but I'm guessing that after you start recording with `ffmpeg`, then in `pavucontrol` switching from _Built-in Audio Analog Stereo_ to _Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo_ doesn't include both the mic and the game does it? Also, please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output from your command.

Comment: No, it includes the game only (and any other sound that comes through my speakers) If you have a better script I'm all ears, took me weeks to dig that one up, most of the other ffmpeg ones I tried wouldn't work, this one actually did with only minor tweaking.   I've had bad experiances switching away from PA in the past, but I've never had an issue with it, unlike most people apparently do ><